# Error no retorna un objeto

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Me aparece un error de que el data no retorna un objeto, estoy usando el framework VUE, aun estoy aprendiendo, De antemano les agradezco.

```
<template>
    <h3>{{ counter }}</h3>
    <button @click="addCounter">Aumenta</button>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
    export default defineComponent({
        name: "CounterOption",
        data(){
            let counter = 0;
            {return counter}
        },
        methods: {
            addCounter(){
                this.counter++; 
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Y si retornas un objeto?... así: `data() { return { counter: 0 } }`

Comment: muchas gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Esta mal definido, hazlo así:

> data(){ return{ counter: 0, } }

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.